# Placement of Totaling of last is not in correct order

Tags: sql-server

I have written the following query to append Total after each Class Type to display total no of attendance after each class.

My Query Output is following
[image]

I have written the following query to show Total after/bellow each Name.

```
DECLARE @tblMissingAttendance TABLE (Name varchar(20), AttendanceDate DATE);



INSERT INTO @tblMissingAttendance VALUES
('KG 1-A'   ,'2019-04-09'),
('GR 10-A'  ,'2019-04-09'),
('GR 10-B'  ,'2019-04-09'),
('GR 10-B'  ,'2019-04-08'),
('GR 10-B'  ,'2019-04-06'),
('GR 10-B'  ,'2019-04-05'),
('GR 10-B'  ,'2019-04-03'),
('GR 10-B'  ,'2019-04-02'),
('GR 10-B'  ,'2019-04-01'),
('GR 10-B'  ,'2019-03-30');



Select Name, AttendanceDate 
                        From @tblMissingAttendance;

;with cteTemp as (Select Name,AttendanceDate 
                        From @tblMissingAttendance
                        )


Select Name,CAST(AttDate as VARCHAR) FROM (SELECT Name, 
        CAST(AttendanceDate as varchar) as AttDate,
        1 AS Total,
        Name as t
        FROM cteTemp AS ma
UNION ALL

SELECT 'Total', 
        CAST(sum(1) as varchar),
        sum(1),
        Name as t
        FROM cteTemp AS ma
        GROUP BY Name
) as ma
ORDER BY t,Total
```

OutPut image that is not correct
[image]

Comment: The order looks correct to me (for what you've asked), if you put `t` into the `SELECT` list you see why: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2cb830830c679c5934a17db01c3a0288). What order *are* you expecting? Why not use `ROLLUP` instead if you want aggregates for group sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is order by varchar issue, i have added another column to fixed the order by issue.

```
Select Name,CAST(AttDate as VARCHAR) FROM (SELECT Name, 
        CAST(AttendanceDate as varchar) as AttDate,
        1 AS Total,
        Name as t,
        0 AS OrderBy
        FROM cteTemp AS ma
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', 
        CAST(sum(1) as varchar),
        sum(1),
        Name as t,
        1 AS OrderBy
        FROM cteTemp AS ma
        GROUP BY Name
) as ma
ORDER BY t,OrderBy
```

Comment: Great! It's working perfectly. Thank you very much @Hasan

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using SUM(1), you should be using COUNT(*). And for the Total column, you can simply use a 2. Your Total and t columns have confusing names. You'd be better naming them to something more relevant to what they do. Something else to note is that you should always specify the length of your strings.

```
SELECT  Name,
        CAST(AttDate as VARCHAR(10)) 
FROM (SELECT Name, 
            CAST(AttendanceDate as varchar(10)) as AttDate,
            1 AS [GroupOrder],
            Name as [GroupName]
        FROM cteTemp AS ma
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'Total' AS Name, 
            CAST(COUNT(*) as varchar(10)),
            2 AS [GroupOrder],
            Name as [GroupName]
        FROM cteTemp AS ma
        GROUP BY Name) as ma
ORDER BY GroupName, GroupOrder;
```